# JSP Error: According to TLD, tag form:input must be empty, but is not

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I try to create form in JSP and have one problem with input field.
Here is part of my JSP page:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Add new PC or Laptop</h4>
        <div class="form">
            <form:form method="post" action="/app/pc/add" class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="pc" role="form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="number">PC Number</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:input id="number" placeholder="Number" path="number">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cpu">CPU</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:input id="cpu" placeholder="CPU" path="cpu">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="hdd">HDD size</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:input id="hdd" placeholder="HDD size" path="hdd">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="os">OS</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:select id="os" path="os">
                            <c:forEach items="<%=com.springapp.mvc.entities.OpSystem.values()%>" var="value">
                                <option value="${value}">${value}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="office">Office</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:input id="office" placeholder="Office version" path="office">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <form:button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is my Controller class:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.controllers;

import com.springapp.mvc.entities.ComputerRepository;
import com.springapp.mvc.entities.OpSystem;
import com.springapp.mvc.entities.Pc;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Created by aleksandrs on 12/27/13.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class AppController {
    @Autowired
    private ComputerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView getIndex(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("act","");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pc/list")
    public ModelAndView getPCList(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("act","devices");
        model.addObject("include","pc_list");
        model.addObject("list",repository.findAll());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pc/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addPc(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("include","pc_add");
        model.addObject("act","devices");
        model.addObject("osTypes", OpSystem.values());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pc/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView savePc(@ModelAttribute("pc") Pc pc, BindingResult result){
        repository.save(pc);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/app/pc/list");
    }

}
```

And here is an Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [/WEB-INF/pages/pc_add.jsp (line: 19, column: 24) According to TLD, tag form:input must be empty, but is not] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/pc_add.jsp (line: 19, column: 24) According to TLD, tag form:input must be empty, but is not
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1633)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1002)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1274)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1664)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1002)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1274)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(index_jsp.java:278)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(index_jsp.java:240)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Where I have error? Or may be I forgot some dependency in POM file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You forgot to close your input tags:

```
<form:input id="hdd" placeholder="HDD size" path="hdd">
```

should be

```
<form:input id="hdd" placeholder="HDD size" path="hdd" />
```

Also note that the following is invalid:

```
<form:button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
```

The closing tag (`</button>`) must match the opening tag (`<form:button>`)

Comment: But only I have one more error now with target object:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/pc_add.jsp at line 19

18:                     <div class="controls">
19:                         <form:input id="number" placeholder="Number" path="number"/>
20:                     </div>
  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'pc' available as request attribute
 org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)

Comment: You need to have a 'pc' request attribute, of type `Pc`, before forwrding to your view. This object contains the initial values of the form elements.

Comment: Also, if you have any xml comments, like <!-- some comment -->, you would see the same error.

Comment: The above solution works like a charm. Just adding the closing  slash for closing the input tag, and violla! Everything worked as expected